# How to load local files in react native based on id in component?

Tags: react-native, local-database

I need to load an item in one component, based on its id which came from props.

I tried to use `fetch`, but it can't load local file.

Also tried `import from`, but it has to be in the beginning of file, not in component.

I want something like this:

```
const Detail = (props) => {
  let id = props.data;
  let path = './book/'+id+'.json';
  var bookData = require(path);
  return (
    <Container>
      <Header></Header>
      <Content>
        <Text>ID: {id}</Text>
        <Text>{bookData}</Text>
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never tried anything like this but try changing your return to

```
return ({ ID: {id, ...bookData} })
```

Comment: that won't work. The issue is CAN NOT load data from local file from component

Comment: might be easier to flatten all your .json files into a books.json, then import it into your container. Then your Detail component can grab values through props.

Comment: Think about it, if it has 100,000 books, it will be super slow and inefficient

Comment: You could use a database, would make your app size smaller too.